# Google Maps for Rails - Place Marker with User Location in Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am trying to place a marker with the users current location.

However I am failing to even get the User Location in the callback.
It seems that the console.log call is triggered before the geocoding of the browser
What am I doing wrong?

haml view

```
= gmaps(:map_options => {:center_on_user => true})

- content_for :scripts do
  :javascript
    Gmaps.map.callback = function () {
      console.log(Gmaps.map.userLocation)
    }
```

html output

```
<div class="map_container"> 
  <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map"></div>
</div>   


<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js"></script>       


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.center_on_user = true;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>

<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    Gmaps.map.callback = function () {
      console.log(Gmaps.map.userLocation)
    }
  //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of this callback, the user location is not already retrieved, it just means the map is done displaying.

Think about this: the user has to decide whether or not he accepts browser geolocation so it could take very long.

I didn't need some callback for geolocation Success, I only created one for geolocation Failure.

You should simply patch the js/coffee in your assets and call whatever function you need at [this line](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L81).

Comment: It would be great if you could provide an example of the patch I am having trouble Getting this to work

Comment: It's been added in the gem: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/commit/e4815ee22e0586f7d6527a1e0443691fb769f114